# create an atm account that gives you a list of what you want to do in that application. create an account, login using java

Tags: try-catch, java.util.scanner, random-access

i'm trying to create an atm account that gives you a list of what you want to do in that application. create an account, login and exit using java, then you can be able to login after beign given a random account number with your desiredpin, operations can follow. but i've been having faults creating the login and create account info.

i tried using scanner and system.input to access inputs from users and create an object of the scanner but while creating it, the info are not been saved, like the account of a person who already has an account